# how to use different versions of SQLite dll's in UWP Library and UWP Application respectively

Tags: .net, uwp, c#-3.0

I am Building a Library in the UWP platform for UWP applications. I need to used SQLite dll in the library,say I am using 3.23.0. If the Uwp application is referring to a different version of SQLite dll say, 3.26.2. Then there might be a version conflict for the developer. How can I handle this situation?.

Comment: Hi, under the same project, it is best to unify the version of the dll, which should not be difficult. Can you tell me why you want to import different versions of `sqlite.dll`?

Comment: I am developing a UWP library which uses SQLite if the project using my library also uses SQLite, then, the Nuget Hell problem would arise. That is the reason I want to know how I can use different versions of SQLite DLL's.

Comment: Hi, you have created the class library, and then you can create `Sqlite` related methods in the class library to focus your methods on data processing. In other words, only reference `Sqlite` in the class library, UWP project reference class library, and use the method, instead of directly writing `Sqlite-related` code in the UWP project, which is more conducive to code decoupling and reuse.

Comment: I am actually developing the library for applications which may or may not use SQLite, I am creating a nuget Package to be precise. Please suggest a way so that my SQLite can be independent from theirs.

Comment: Hi, If you are looking for information about generating a nuget package and creating a reference, then this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/select-assemblies-referenced-by-projects) can help you. In fact, for sqlite, you can reference different versions when creating nuget package, but you should ensure version compatibility. If you still have questions about this, consider creating a new thread and using the `nuget` tag to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont worry, Now you can easily use two versions of SQLite, one for your library and the other for your project.You can refer your specified version in your library and build it and get the .dll in "Release" mode. Now, you can use this library in your project and then, you can use your required version in your project.